# iterate array combination method with .any method

Tags: ruby, combinations, enumerable, any

Is there anyway to iterate through different combinations of arrays?

I'm writing a program that returns true if the largest number in an array can be the sum of any of the members of the array.

This is my code: (forgive me, i learned how to program 2 weeks ago for the first time)

```
def ArrayAdditionI(arr)
arr=arr.sort
largest=arr.pop
n=arr.length
  for i in 1..n
    if arr.combination(i).to_a.any? {|array| array.inject(:+)==largest}
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end
end
```

i tested it for
    a = [1,2,3,4]
and it returned false even though clearly, 3+1 = 4.
When I change the above code from arr.combination(i) to arr.combination(2) its returns true. So I'm guessing it has something to do with the combination method not being able to be looped. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `return false` in the wrong place. As it is, `false` is returned is there is no combination of one element (i.e., one element other than the one you've removed after sorting) that sums (i.e., is equal to) `largest`. Rather you want to return `false` only if no combination of any size sums to `largest`.  This is what you need:

```
def max_match?(arr)
  arr=arr.sort
  largest=arr.pop
  n=arr.length
  for i in 1..n
    return true if arr.combination(i).any? {|array|
      array.inject(:+)==largest}
  end
  false
end

arr = [1,4,7,3,5,2,13]
max_match?(arr) #=> true
arr = [1,3,4,7,59]
max_match?(arr) #=> false
```

A few notes:

- lower case letters and optional underscores are used for names of methods.  You can also put a question (`?`) or explanation (`!`) mark at the end.  Here a question mark seems appropriate.
- `to_a` is not needed. Enumerable methods (e.g., `any?`) can have Enumerators as receivers.
- sorting is expensive and unnecessary.  Instead, just get the max value and remove it from the array.  (Aside: you didn't say what happens if the maximum value appears more than once. See the code below and the last sentence.)
- you don't need `n=arr.length`. `for i in 1..arr.length` is enough, except...
- `for ...` is rarely used.  Rubyists tend to use `each` instead, or one of the many methods from the [Enumerable](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html) (mix-in) module (all of which invoke `each`).
- you don't need `return false` because Ruby returns the value of the last statement evaluated, which is `false` if the method does not return `true` earlier.

Here's a more Ruby-like way to do that:

```
def max_match?(arr)
  mx = arr.max
  whats_left = arr - [mx]
  (1..whats_left.size).any? {|n| whats_left.combination(n).any? {|c|
    c.reduce(:+) == mx }}
end

arr = [1,4,7,3,5,2,13]
max_match?(arr) #=> true
arr = [1,3,4,7,59]
max_match?(arr) #=> false
```

If you wish this to return `true` when `arr` contains more than one value equal to `mx`, insert the following after `mx = arr.max`:

```
return true if arr.count(mx) > 1
```

Comment: my question, was why were you able to iterate combination through any, but i couldn't do it with a for loop? in my above code. Thank you for your response though, it was very helpful

Comment: `arr - [mx]` removes *all* occurrences of `mx`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, @Stefan. The OP's code removes just one element, but I wasn't sure if that was the intent.  I alluded to the issue in the third bullet point, but will clarify with an edit.